Yarn/Npm package vulnerabilities upon initializing a new Anchor project
Relatively new to Anchor/Solana.
I have set up the Anchor/Solana development environment successfully, the newly created projects (with anchor init NAME) build and run without issues.
However, one thing has been bugging me and I seem not to find any answers. Upon creating a new Anchor project with said command above, I get Yarn warnings about outdated and vulnerable packages in the project, which seem important: 
warning mocha > glob@7.2.0: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
warning mocha > glob > inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.

Also, running yarn audit shows this:
 
Is this normal when working with the Anchor framework and should I ignore these "vulnerabilities"?
Or should I pursue some kind of solution to these issues? (If so, I would appreciate your help in solving this)
This has been bugging me for quite a while since vulnerabilities in production code is a serious issue and I'd like to address it properly.
Technical specifications: 
OS: Linux Mint 21.2 
Anchor version: anchor-0.30.1 
Solana version: solana-cli 1.18.17 
RustC version: 1.83.0 
NodeJS version: v22.12.0 
Yarn version: 1.22.22 
Mocha version: 9.2.2 
If any additional info should be provided, please do tell :)

It's probably expected, but feel free to contribute a package update to https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor !
